# Add conditions to a pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, pagination

The following script pulls the data from my database and creates a pagination.

The pagination works, but I would like to add a conditional statement which differentiates the level of the user. User level could be New, Current or Renewing client.

I am not sure how or where to add the conditional statement. I created level_styles in my css so a div style can be added, but how.

Any help will be appreciated. This is the [plugin](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.VVFHFPlViko) that I used.

Thanks

```
var columns = ["username", "user_id", "address", "state", "postal_code", "phone", "email"];
var level_classes = {
  "NEW": "new_client",
  "RENEWAL": "renewing_client",
  "CURRENT": "current_client"
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj = '';
  $.getJSON("obtainUsers.php", function(data) {
    var num = 1;
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
    var html = "";
    var tot_obj = obj.length;
    var highest = (num * 8) - 1;
    var lowest = (num * 8) - 8;
    var maximum = (highest < total_users) ? highest : total_users;
    for (var i = lowest; i <= maximum; i++) {
      var toggle = i % 2;
      var textTab = " ";
      for (var x = 0; x < columns.length; x++) {
        if (typeof obj[i][columns[x]] === 'undefined' || obj[i][columns[x]] === "") {
          continue;
        }
        var tmp = "";
        if (obj[i][columns[x]] instanceof Object) {
          tmp += obj[i][columns[x]];
        }
        if (tmp && tmp !== ' ') {
          textTab += tmp;
        }
        textTab += "<br />";
      }
      if (toggle == 0) {
        html += "<div style='text-align: center;'>";
        html += textTab;
        html += "</div>";
      } else {
        html += "<div style='text-align: center;'>";
        html += textTab;
        html += "</div>";
      }
    }
    $('.testid').html(html);
  });
  $('.pagination, .pagination_bottom').bootpag({
    total: 20,
    page: 1,
    leaps: false,
    next: 'next',
    prev: 'prev',
    maximumVisible: 3
  }).on('page', function(event, num) {
    var html = "";
    var total_users = obj.length;
    var highest = (num * 9) - 1;
    var lowest = (num * 9) - 9;
    var maximum = (highest < total_users) ? highest : total_users;
    for (var i = lowest; i < maximum; i++) {
      var toggle = i % 2;
      var textTab = " ";
      for (var x = 0; x < columns.length; x++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < columns.length; x++) {
          if (typeof obj[i][columns[x]] === 'undefined' || obj[i][columns[x]] === "") {
            continue;
          }
          var tmp = "";
          if (obj[i][columns[x]] instanceof Object) {
            tmp += obj[i][columns[x]];
          }
          if (tmp && tmp !== ' ') {
            textTab += tmp;
          }
          textTab += "<br />";
        }
        if (toggle == 0) {
          html += "<div style='text-align: center;'>";
          html += textTab;
          html += "</div>";
        } else {
          html += "<div style='text-align: center;'>";
          html += textTab;
          html += "</div>";
        }
      }
      $('.runningList').html(html);
      var total_pages = Math.ceil(obj.length / 10);
      $('.pagination_bottom').bootpag({
        page: num,
        total: total_pages
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: These were typos, my apologies

Comment: Do you have a sample that I could see? I am not concerned with them changing their level yet, I kinda want to understand how to do the div change per user. The page is going to be more for show than for making changes to their actual account.

Comment: So you don't believe what I am trying to do is simple? I not sure how to do it the other way, this is how I learned so far and I want it to apply it more. So for example can this work? `if( columns[x] == "user_level")`

Comment: That a great start, I just need to figure out how to set it once and not let it run again and again.

Comment: Could you explain more? The user level where is located at? DB ¡

Comment: Thank @humble.rumble.6x3 for the help. I got it to work but now I have problem with the pagination plugin that will not show new elements from page 3 forward, but that's another post.
@Skatox the `user_level` is one of the columns in my database, is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing

```
if( columns[x] == "user_level" && obj[i][columns[x]] == new_user )
{
    textTab += "<span class='new_user'>";
}                                
else if ( columns[x] == "user_level" && obj[i][columns[x]] == current_user )
{
    textTab += "<span class='current_user'>";
}
else if ( columns[x] == "user_level" && obj[i][columns[x]] == renew_user )
{
    textTab += "<span class='renewing_user'>";
}
```

I created the three variables `new_user`, `current_user` and `renew_user`. I added this conditions here

```
if (typeof obj[i][columns[x]] === 'undefined' || obj[i][columns[x]] === "") {
      continue;
    }
//Added the conditions here
var tmp = "";
```

Thank you so much [@humble.rumble.6x3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/humble-rumble-6x3)

Comment: If this worked, select this as the answer. Even if it's yourself